# Creating binding wrappers for SuperPoweredSDK in xamarin?

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, static-libraries, superpowered

I have been trying to create binding for SuperPowered SDK in xamarin.ios.

I have cloned this repository (https://bitbucket.org/bryonbaker/xamarin-spectrum-analyser) and have added a wrapper for advanced audio player both in xcode wrapper and xamarin wrapper as well.

It appears to have binding working in my xamarin.ios project, having said that, when using AdvancedAudioPlayer's Play() method, it doesn't produce any sound.

I have created a git repo where the code has been pushed. I wish someone could look into and let me know where I have missed anything.

https://github.com/Dhruvbhagat/SuperPoweredBinding.git

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any audio I/O in the repo. The player is a "DSP object", outputting floating point audio data. If that data is not consumed by an audio I/O, then nothing will really happen.